# Javascript get callback from function within map

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, async-await

I have been struggling with this for quite sometime and haven't been able to find a good solution for this problem.

I have an array which I map through an imported function that has a call back. I want to get the data(JSON) from the callback, manipulate it, output it and run it through another function.

Because the node_module qbo.getBill function has a callback, I don't think I can run promise or async\await, well I haven't had any success doing so as soon as I add the getBill function.

Here is my code/what I am trying to do:

```js
var QuickBooks = require('node-quickbooks') 
        var qbo = new QuickBooks(...)

        let BillIds = [....]
        let newArray =[]

        let mapData = BillIds.map(val => {
            qbo.getBill(val, function (err, Billid) {
                newArray.push = {
                  id: Billid.Id,
                  balance: Billid.Balance
                }
            })
        })
        
        
        
        DoAThingWithAsyncronousData(newArray)
```

For the life of me I can't get any action to wait on the the asynchronous data before completing the next step, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why function `map` when you're only looping?

Comment: I started with a loop, then after a fair stack of reading changed to a map and I am not really sure why I have a map now.

Would a loop solve this problem?

Comment: `getBill` returns a promise?

Comment: getBill has a callback, so no promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use Promise.all, you just need to put a promise around `getBill`'s callback:

```
const newArray = await Promise.all(
  BillIds.map(val => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    qbo.getBill(val, (err, Billid) => {
      const billObj = {
        id: Billid.Id,
        balance: Billid.Balance
      }
      resolve(billObj)
    });
  }))
);

DoAThingWithAsyncronousData(newArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I get an error for the await in  `const new array = await Promise.all` however if I remove it it seems to work.

Edit: Oh yes,  I need to  put it inside a async function and that works perfect :)